# Trying to make second instance of NDI Webcam Input (Virtual Input)

Tags: input, virtual, webcam

I come across this post
https://dev.to/xreyrobertibm/quick-hack-to-use-multiple-instances-of-newtek-ndi-scan-converter-on-macos-10eb
It is about making second instance of NDI Scan Converter on MacOS and I got idea to try it with NDI Webcam Input (Virtual Input). But...

Using HxD hex editor to edit exe file (copy), I was able to change application name from Network Webcam to Network Webcan (it has to be the exact same length) and after saving it now I can load second instance of application. It works but both instances present in programs menus as NewTek NDI Video and conflict each other.

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the NDI plugin tool for OBS and add multiple instances that way.  Here's the creator's GitHub repo. https://github.com/Palakis/obs-ndi/releases